# CSS Dropdown menu problem

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I created a css dropdown menu so my site will work with iphones.  The dropdown is working correctly except for when you hover over a dropdown the sub items in the menu expand but when you hover over them the image on the main dropdown item looses it's color.  I have it setup so that a different image is displayed when the mouse is hovering over it.  Here is a link to pretty much the same code I have on my website.  I just want the image to stay the same whether I am hovering over the main menu item or the subitems.  Any help would be much appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/h5xZT/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update your code it's simple.  That should set you on your way.  There is no need to use the "button" within a li item.

http://jsfiddle.net/h5xZT/19/